# Can't see the top of a form in datasheet mode in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a form that has a tab control with 4 pages. (frmEntry)
One of the pages also has a tab control with 2 pages.  (SpendPlan)
To create this, I had to use a subform control (frmStage)  to put the 2 pages.

frmStage also has a subform in one of the pages   - frmSP that is a datasheet form.

To make a long story short, I've been trying to tweak the design make it possible to see all of the records in frmSP - just about 160 records in the window.

I did something that is now preventing me from seeing the header row of frmSP.
There's almost no way to find a solution to this using Google, so here I am.  Any insight would be most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

when your subform gets focus it moved back to a centered position (don't know why) and there are no properties to prevent this. only way to prevent this is to reduce the subform size to match within the parent form.

or you could take use of Anchoring ;)

Comment: Does anchoring have anything to do with how much you're able to see?  I also would like to be able to see the last 3 end columns of my subform, but no matter how much I open up the main form, the horizontal bar just grows and I never can see the last 3 columns of that subform.

Comment: Anchoring can "Anchor" your components to a form, either left, right, or stretch across the form. It means if you maximize your form your components will be stretched automatically. I have never tried to set the column with in a datasheet but i guess you can do it by setting .ColumnWidth = width_in_twips
get the inner form width divide by your columns and set the width